# Are artifactory properties attached to an artefact replicated to edge node when i distribute a release bundle

Tags: artifactory

1. I upload an artefact with property `x=value`
2. I create a Release bundle including this artefact
3. I distribute this artefact to an edge node

I would like to retrieve the property `x=<value>` attached to the artefact in the edge node.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course it is possible.
Once the Release Bundle distributed to the Edge node, the artifacts are stored on the respective repositories on the Edge node. Then, you can query the Edge node as usual (exactly as Artifactory - see [Artifactory AQL Get Specific Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36755962/artifactory-aql-get-specific-properties)).